# Get workflowApplication state

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

We would like to know if there is some way to get the current state (Running, Idle, Completed,...) of a workflow instance, using workflowapplication hosting.

When the application is shouting down, we want to wait for idle (or completed) state of all our workflow instances(we have a collection of them) in order to be persisted in the instance store.

We know that we can get the state when we get idle, completed, aborted,... events, but we need to get the status at anytime...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box status property you can check for this. However using workflow tracking this is quite easy to implement.